# sql setting mutiple values in one cross apply / case expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, cross-apply

I'm trying to clean up the query below.  In the first cross apply, I evaluate the `[Store Number]` and `[Branch Number]` and return the `[Store Name]`, then in the following three cross applys, I use this `[Store Name]` to return values individually for `[Phone Number]`, `[Contact Name]` and `[Contact Title]`.  Is there a way to set and return all three of these values in only one additional cross apply/case?

```
SELECT

       C.[Store Number]
       ,B.[Store Name]
       ,PH.[Phone Number]
      ,CN.[Contact Name]
      ,CT.[Contact Title]
  FROM [Central_Account] C 

      cross apply (select[Store Name] = case C.[Store Number]
                                 when 9146 then
                                    case
                                          when C.[Branch Number] In (14, 16, 18)
                                          then 'Community Store'
                                    end  
                                 when 8147 Then 
                                    case
                                          when C.[Branch Number] In (24, 26, 28)
                                          then 'City Store'
                                    end
                                 when 7148 Then 
                                   case
                                          when C.[Branch Number] In (34, 36, 38)
                                          then 'County Store'
                                   end
                                 else
                                    'State Store'
                           end )as B
        cross apply (select [Phone Number] = case B.[Store Name]
                       when 'Community Store' Then
                                      '414.882.8278'       
                                 when 'City Store' Then
                                      '221.332.6221'
                                 when 'County Store' Then
                                    '211.949.2008'
                                 else
                                    '635.588.1878'
                           end ) as PH                        
      cross apply (select [Contact Name] = case B.[Store Name]
                                when 'Community Store' Then
                                      'John A. Smith'      
                                 when 'City Store' Then
                                      'Marcus D. Jones'
                                 when 'County Store' Then
                                      'Mica L. Johnson'
                                 else
                                      'Elroy Watkins, Jr.'
                           end ) as CN   
        cross apply (select [Contact Title] = case B.[Store Name]
                                when 'Community Store' Then
                                      'Executive Vice President'      
                                 when 'City Store' Then
                                      'Manager'
                                 when 'County Store' Then
                                      'President of Operations'
                                 else
                                      'Clerk'
                           end ) as CT
```

Comment: Phew, all these `CASE`s. You should store that data (e.g. a store's phone number) in tables and join them. Don't "store" data in queries.

Comment: Agreed. . .this information should already be stored somewhere.  Not certain why query isn't pulling from table sources.  Will dig a bit further.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My inclination would be to treat this like a `join`.

```
select C.[Store Number], sn.Store_Name, 
       v.phone_number, v.contact_name, v.contact_title
from Central_Account C cross apply
     (values (case when C.[Store Number] = 9146 and C.[Branch Number] In (14, 16, 18)
                   then 'Community Store'
                   when C.[Store Number] = 8147 and C.[Branch Number] In (24, 26, 28)
                   then 'City Store'
                   when C.[Store Number] = 7148 and C.[Branch Number] In (34, 36, 38)
                   then 'County Store'
                   when C.[Store Number] not in (9146, 8147, 7148)
                   then 'State Store'
              end)
     ) sn(store_name) join
     (values ('Community Store', '414.882.8278', 'John A. Smith', 'Executive Vice President'), 
             ('City Store', '221.332.6221', 'Marcus D. Jones',  'Manager'),
             ('County Store', '211.949.2008', 'Mica L. Johnson', 'President of Operations'),
             ('State Store', '635.588.1878', 'Elroy Watkins, Jr.', 'Clerk')
     ) v(store_name, phone_number, contact_name, contact_title)
     on sn.store_name = v.store_name or
        (sn.store_name is null and v.store_name = 'State Store';
```

The first `cross apply` gets the store name.  The second `values` then brings in all the relevant information about the store.  There is this little trick with the defaults -- because some store names are `NULL` as you have set up the logic.  That just defaults to the state store.

Comment: This worked perfectly-nice and clean too!  Thanks for you help! *****